# Rotina Form_Load não funciona

Tags: visual-basic-6

Tenho um formulário 'frmPerfis' que ao abrir ele executa a rotina 'RotinaRefresh' (para atualizar dados de um listview) que está dentro do 'Form_Load'.
Dentro deste form tem o form 'frmPerfisAlterar' e quando o chamo e salvo as alterações no registro ele grava as informações e depois faz o seguinte(fecha o form atual e vai para o 'frmPerfis':

...
    Unload Me
        frmPerfis.Show
...

Ao abrir o 'frmPerfis' entendo que a rotina do 'Form_Load' (a 'RotinaRefresh') deveria ser executada para que o listview venha com os dados atualizados. Porém isso não ocorre.
Como posso fazer isso funcionar?

Comment: Utlizei depois do Unload Me o código:
...
        Call frmPerfis.RotinaRefresh
...

Coloquei a 'RotinaRefresh' como pública e chamei ela de outro form.

Answer (score 0):

O que está aparecendo é que o formulário "frmPerfis" não foi descarregado após invocar o formulário "frmPerfisAlterar".

O que costumo fazer para não deixar o formulário carregado e as variáveis preenchidas é criar um objeto e trabalhar com ele.

```
Dim f2 As Form2

Set f2 = New Form2

f2.Show

Call Unload(Me)

Set f2 = Nothing
```

Ou ainda como dependo da "resposta" de outro fomulário costumo abrir em vbmodal e aguarda sua execução.

```
Dim f2 As frmPerfisAlterar

Set f2 = New frmPerfisAlterar

f2.Show vbModal

Call RotinaRefresh

Set f2 = Nothing
```